# How to remove tokens from a list in cmake?

Tags: build, makefile, cmake

I want to exclude some source files from building when not in Windows.
What is wrong in the following CMakeLists.txt cmake file?

```
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

# Remove Microsoft specific files
message(${SRC_LIST})

list(REMOVE_ITEM SRC_LIST stdafx.h stdafx.cpp)

message("------------------")
message(${SRC_LIST})
```

The contents of the messages before and after trying to remove the two files are exactly the same.

What is wrong?

Comment: So far, this looks correct. The problem is probably with the contents of `SRC_LIST`. Make sure that it is indeed a list (that is, a string with values separated by semicolons) and that it contains both `stdafx.h` and `stdafx.cpp` as singular (!) elements.

Comment: I get a list of NON separated files: ./file1.cpp./file2.cpp./file3.cpp  - How can I add a semicolon separator?

Comment: This looks okay. `message` has a peculiar formatting for lists, so they look like they are not separated at all. You should only be worried if you see spaces as separators.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to specify the *exact* name of the element you want to remove.

In your case, `aux_source_directory` prepends each entry with a `./`, so the correct command has to be

```
list(REMOVE_ITEM SRC_LIST ./stdafx.h ./stdafx.cpp)
```

Also, please make sure you understand the implications of using manual calls to `aux_source_directory` for maintaining lists of source files:

> It is tempting to use this command to avoid writing the list of source
>   files for a library or executable target. While this seems to work,
>   there is no way for CMake to generate a build system that knows when a
>   new source file has been added. Normally the generated build system
>   knows when it needs to rerun CMake because the CMakeLists.txt file is
>   modified to add a new source. When the source is just added to the
>   directory without modifying this file, one would have to manually
>   rerun CMake to generate a build system incorporating the new file.

Quoting [the documentation for `aux_source_directory`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/aux_source_directory.html).